# Check if Seq[T] contains Option[T]

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following

```
case class Foo(a: Option[Int])
val bar = Seq(Foo(Some(0)), Foo(Some(1)), Foo(None))
val baz = Seq(0, 2)
```

and I want to check whether `a` of type `Option[Int]` exists in `Seq[Int]`

This doesn't work

```
bar.map {
  case foo: Foo if !baz.contains(foo.a) => Foo(None)
  case foo: Foo => foo  
}
```

Since `a` is of type `Option[Int]` so `contains(foo.a)` always returns `false`

I know I can do something like either of the following

```
bar.map {
  case foo: Foo if foo.a.isEmpty || !baz.contains(foo.a.get) => Foo(None)
  case foo: Foo => foo  
}
bar.map {
  case Foo(None) => Foo(None)
  case Foo(Some(a)) if !baz.contains(a) => Foo(None)
  case foo: Foo => foo
}
```

But I wonder if there another way, basically a `containsOption` or any other interesting approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if there exists a value in an `Option` that is contained in a `List` we can write

```
Some(2).exists(baz.contains)           // true
Some(1).exists(baz.contains)           // false
Option.empty[Int].exists(baz.contains) // false
```

thus if you are trying to filter `bar` on such predicate then

```
bar.filter(_.a.exists(baz.contains))
// List(Foo(Some(0)))
```

whilst trying to answer the question directly

```
bar.map(foo => if (foo.a.exists(baz.contains)) foo else Foo(None))
// List(Foo(Some(0)), Foo(None), Foo(None))
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was something like that I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this approach:

```
bar.collect {
  case Foo(Some(v)) => v
}.intersect(baz).nonEmpty
```

Collect all elements which are present in `Foo`, then perform intersection with `baz` collection. The result is `true` if there are elements in `bar` collection that exist in `baz` collection.